# Why can't I get the input name when sending a PHP email

Tags: php, html, email

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];//check here i want this both to send to my email with user input
$email = $_POST['email'];//check here i want this both to send to my email with user input
echo $name;
$email = "mymail@gmail.com";
$to = "myemail@gmail.com";
$subject = "Hi!";
$body = "Hi,How are you?";
$headers = 'From: ' .$email . "\r\n".'Reply-To: ' . $email. "\r\n".'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $name, $headers)) echo("<p>Email successfully sent</p>");
else echo("<p>Email delivery failed</p>");
?>
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>PHP form to email sample form</title>
<!-- define some style elements-->



</head>


<body>

    <form action="sendmail.php" method="post">
    <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
    <li>Name: <input type="text" name="name" size="30" maxlength="40"></li>
    <li>&nbsp;</li>
    <li>Email: <input type="text" name="email" size="30" maxlength="40"></li>
    <li>&nbsp;</li>

    <li><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send"></li>
    </ul>
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

I have successfully received the mail sent to my email account, however I have an input `name` and `email` that I cannot get to send in the message? What have I done wrong? Can anyone help me fix it?

Comment: You overwriting the `$email` variable with `mymail@gmail.com`. You'll never get the input value with this line present...

Comment: You are overwriting the `$email` variable with `$email = "mymail@gmail.com";`

Comment: [`bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Comment: Are you trying to add name to the e-mail headers or body?

Answer (score 1):

You're not passing parameters to the mail function correctly:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

If you want the name to show up in the mail headers, do this:

```
$headers = 'From: ' . $name . '<' . $email . '>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $name . '<' . $email . '>' "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

If you're trying to get the name in the body, do this:

```
$body = 'Hi ' . $name . ', How are you?';
```

Then call the function without the $name argument:

```
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)
```

Thanks,

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Name should be on the headers. Try this on header and remove the $name from the mail functi

```
$name.` <`.$email.`>`;
```